# Couldn't Setup method for mock passed into list of objects c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, moq

While mocking I ran into some problems.

```
 private Mock<IPaymentHandler> _mockRecurringPaymentHandler;
 private Mock<IPaymentHandler> _mockRecurringPaymentFailedHandler;
 private IEnumerable<IPaymentHandler> _paymentManagers;

_mockRecurringPaymentHandler = new Mock<IPaymentHandler>();
_mockRecurringPaymentFailedHandler = new Mock<IPaymentHandler>();

_paymentManagers = new List<IPaymentHandler>
{
    _mockRecurringPaymentHandler.Object,
    _mockRecurringPaymentFailedHandler.Object
};

_sut = new PaypaIIpnManager(
    _paymentManagers,
    _mockLogger.Object
    );
```

And when lately I try to setup a method for `mockRecurringPaymentHandler`, e.g below:

```
_mockRecurringPaymentHandler.Setup(method => method.GetPaymentType()).Returns("GFDGDFGDFG");
```

It doesn't work. It works only if I do it before passing it to list.
Why does this have such behavior?

```
public PaypaIIpnManager(
            IEnumerable<IPaymentHandler> paymentHandlers,
            ILoggerService<PaypaIIpnManager> logger)
        {
            _handlersDic = RegisterStrategy(paymentHandlers);
            _logger = logger;
        }

protected Dictionary<string, IPaymentHandler> RegisterStrategy(IEnumerable<IPaymentHandler> paymentHandlers)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, IPaymentHandler>();

            foreach (var handler in paymentHandlers)
            {
                var paymentType = handler.GetPaymentType();

                dic.Add(paymentType, handler);
            }

            return dic;
        }
```

Comment: Ideally it should work until you are not changing the reference of `_mockRecurringPaymentHandler` or `PaypaIIpnManager` itself invokes  `GetPaymentType` which is not yet defined so you should define it before passing the List

Comment: Okay, but why the same approach work if we pass not list but single object to sut and after that in one of the methods make setup up it works?

Comment: For list it have different behaviour?

Comment: Does all code shown in question exists in one method?

Comment: No, _paymentManagers = new List<IPaymentHandler>
{
    _mockRecurringPaymentHandler.Object,
    _mockRecurringPaymentFailedHandler.Object
};

_sut = new PaypaIIpnManager(
    _paymentManagers,
    _mockLogger.Object
    ); it exists in Setup method

Comment: How you are using `_paymentManagers` in method under test? I mean how you know that correct `...handler` used there

Comment: @test - it would depend how you have defined the `PaypaIIpnManager` constructors. Can you please post both the version which takes list and the other one which takes object?

Comment: updated with constructor

Comment: Constructor shows nothing, can you show then method where those handlers used?

Comment: and method GetPaymentType() which returns just string, i couldn't mock from my tests ufter initialization PaypalIpnManager

Comment: Did you setup `GetPaymentType` for both handlers? And both not working?

Comment: _mockRecurringPaymentHandler.Setup(method => method.GetPaymentType()).Returns("GFDGDFGDFG");  Yes i setup in the same way other mock, and both didn't work

Comment: @test - When `PaypaIIpnManager` constructor  is invoked  then it calls your `RegisterStrategy` which invokes `GetPaymentType` for your handler. Since before invoking the constructor, the `GetPaymentType` is not setup that's why in your test it is not called. So here, you should define the `GetPaymentType` Setup before you call the constructor.

Comment: Remember unit testing works on a concept of AAA --- Arrange, Act and Assert. Until you don't arrange the things appropriately, act does not work as required.

Comment: oh sheet, you're right. Thanks you a lot!

Comment: I'll post it as answer.

Comment: But what is the best solution over here? Just create PaypalIPNManager in each test method?

Comment: @test - When you do unit Test writing, you should arrange the code so that the unit test can execute against it even if it require duplicating some part of code. So yes, you should create the constructor in each method if each unit test wants to setup Mock object differently..

Comment: @test - if the answer provides the information required to you, then can you please accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Remember unit testing works on a concept of AAA --- Arrange, Act and Assert. Until you don't arrange the things appropriately, act does not work as required.

So here when `PaypaIIpnManager` constructor is invoked then it calls your `RegisterStrategy` which invokes `GetPaymentType` for your mocked handler. Since before invoking the constructor, the `GetPaymentType` is not setup that's why in your test the setup method `GetPaymentType` is not called. So here, you should define the `GetPaymentType` Setup before you call the constructor.